# How to write a query to mach multiple values

Tags: marklogic

I want to write a simple query to search documents with **RequestNumber IN ('ABC','CDC','L11')**. How can I write that in Marklogic query?

Answer (score 5):

Use [cts:search()](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:search) with a [cts:element-value-query()](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:element-value-query) if those are the only values in that element:

```
cts:search(doc(), cts:element-value-query(xs:QName("RequestNumber"), ('ABC','CDC','L11')))
```

Otherwise, you could also use [cts:element-word-query()](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:element-word-query):

```
cts:search(doc(), cts:element-word-query(xs:QName("RequestNumber"), ('ABC','CDC','L11')))
```